# Where did the fanart in episode 5 come from?

Tags: miss-monochrome

In episode 5 there are several pieces of Miss Monochrome cosplay fanart with the main character in swimwear, cat ears, race queen clothes, nurse, doctor, and shrine maiden.

[image: miss monochrome swimwear] 
[image: miss monochrome nekomimi] 
[image: miss monochrome race queen] 
[image: miss monochrome nurse] 
[image: miss monochrome doctor] 
[image: miss monochrome miko]

Where did this fanart come from?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There was a [contest in Pixiv regarding that episode](https://www.pixiv.net/info.php?id=1919&lang=en):

[image: pixiv contest poster]

> Starting September 9th, TV animation, Miss Monochrome, are looking for fresh new cosplay designs with the main character in clothing such as swimwear, cat ears, race queen clothes, nurse, doctor, shrine maiden, etc.
>
> The winning entry or entries will have their work show up in the 5th episode of the Miss Monochrome animation along with a signed poster.

They gave credit to the winner

[image: miss monochrome credit]

And here are the winner (click to get bigger image):

[image: miss monochrome swimwear] [image: miss monochrome nekomimi]
[image: miss monochrome race queen] [image: miss monochrome nurse] [image: miss monochrome doctor] [image: miss monochrome shrine maiden]

And here are the original fanart post on pixiv:

- https://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=medium&illust_id=38685552
- https://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=medium&illust_id=38774657
- https://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=medium&illust_id=38735824
- https://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=medium&illust_id=38822738
- https://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=medium&illust_id=38818662
- https://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=medium&illust_id=38833155 (the shrine maiden art apparently been made private by [the artist](https://www.pixiv.net/member.php?id=1096314))

Here are [all submitted entry](http://www.pixiv.net/contest/monochrome.php) and [the contest winners from Pixiv](https://www.pixiv.net/info.php?id=1993)

Comment: Here's the pixiv post announcing the contest winners: https://www.pixiv.net/info.php?id=1993. The shrine maiden one would be here (https://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=medium&illust_id=38833155) but has apparently been made private by the artist.